# Python pysqlite not accepting my qmark parameterization

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite, python-db-api

I think I am being a bonehead, maybe not importing the right package, but when I do...

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
import types
import re
import sys
...
    def create_asgn(self):
        stmt = "CREATE TABLE ? (login CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, grade INTEGER NOT NULL)"
        stmt2 = "insert into asgn values ('?', ?)"
        self.cursor.execute(stmt, (sys.argv[2],))
        self.cursor.execute(stmt2, [sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]])
...
 I get the error pysqlite2.dbapi2.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

This makes very little sense to me, as the docs show that pysqlite is qmark parametrized.  I am new to python and db-api though, help me out!  THANKS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because parameters can only be passed to VALUES. The table name can't be parametrized.

Also you have quotes around a parametrized argument on the second query. Remove the quotes, escaping is handled by the underlining library automatically for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the quotes in the line that assigns to `stmt2`:

```
    stmt2 = "insert into asgn values (?, ?)"
```

Also, as nosklo says, you can't use question-mark parameterisation with CREATE TABLE statements.  Stick the table name into the SQL directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it, try something like this:

def read(db="projects"):

```
sql = "select * from %s"
sql = sql % db
c.execute(sql)
```

Comment: use the backtick form of table names in the SQL (ie: \`table\` instead of table) and make a function remove_backticks(inputString) that returns inputString with all backticks removed.  Then write the above query (since you provided that example) as such:

`sql="SELECT * from \`%s\`" % remove_backticks(db)`